# Orientdb fails to shut down

Tags: orientdb

This fails:

```
$ sudo service orientdb stop
```

This fails as well:

```
$ sudo /data/db/orientdb/bin/shutdown.sh

Sending shutdown command to remote OrientDB Server instance...
Dec 19, 2015 6:50:09 PM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=991MB (heap=869MB os=3,909MB disk=175,894MB)
Dec 19, 2015 6:50:09 PM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: Loading configuration from: /data/db/orientdb/config/orientdb-server-config.xml...
Error: Read timed out
```

The file permissions are correct:

```
12K -rwxrwx---  1 orientdb orientdb 9.6K Dec 19 18:05 orientdb-server-config.xml
```

If have tried commenting out script that refers to "orientdb-server-config.xml" in the the shutdown.sh file and it makes no difference.

The System:

- Ubuntu v14.04
- OrientDB v2.1.8 (I upgraded from v2.1.6 to see if it would fix this problem)
- Java v1.8

Comment: I've upgrade my OrientDB from 2.1.4 to 2.2.0. Shutdown of 2.1.4 doesn't work in 2.2.0 because I must add parameter about user, password, server and port. Maybe you have the same trouble. Check if in your shutdown these informations are present

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this command. This worked for me when shutting down normally.

```
sh shutdown.sh localhost 2424
```

Answer (score -1):

To stop a running server, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the open shell that runs the server instance, or soft kill the process to be sure that the opened databases close softly. Soft killing on Windows can be done by closing the window. On Unix-like systems, a simple kill is enough (do not use kill -9 unless you want to force a hard shutdown).