# OrientDB as a daemon on Ubuntu not stopping

Tags: linux, ubuntu, orientdb, ubuntu-15.04

Followed the documentation for Installing orientdb on Linux/Ubuntu on the following location, http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Unix-Service.html

Set the following variables : JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME, ORIENTDB_HOME and the following changes in the below files,

**orientdb.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
# OrientDB service script
#
# Copyright (c) Orient Technologies LTD (http://www.orientechnologies.com)

# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: OrientDb init script
# processname: orientdb.sh

# You have to SET the OrientDB installation directory here
ORIENTDB_DIR="/local/some-location"
ORIENTDB_USER="some-user"
```

**Installing for systemmd**
/etc/systemd/system/orientdb.service

```
[Unit]
Description=OrientDB Server
After=network.target
After=syslog.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/local/some-location/bin/orientdb.sh start
ExecStop=/local/some-location/bin/orientdb.sh stop
ExecStatus=/local/some-location/bin/orientdb.sh status
```

It is possible to start the service by the following command

```
systemctl start orientdb.service
```

But the service will not stop after giving the following command

```
systemctl stop orientdb.service
```

Machine Info :

- Java 8.0_31
- Orientdb 2.1.12
- Ubuntu 15.04 on Virtual Box VM

Comment: Are you getting some error? Can you post it and share also logs for investigation? Thanks.

Comment: @OleksandrGubchenko when executing the command "systemctl status orientdb.service" It prints "Stopped OrientDB Server."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your service file according to this:

$ cat /etc/systemd/system/orientdb.service

```
[Unit]
Description=OrientDB Server
After=network.target
After=syslog.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=<USER>
Group=<GROUP>
ExecStart=<ORIENTDB_INSTALL_PATH>/bin/server.sh
SuccessExitStatus=143
```

modifying with your user,group and path.

than reload the service `systemctl daemon-reload`

Using this is working for me on Fedora23.

---

Let me know.

Ivan

---

**EDIT**

Tried on Ubuntu 15.04 and it works.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan. The answer you gave works with some changes to orientdb.service file. To shutdown the service "ExecStop=<ORIENTDB_INSTALL_PATH>/bin/shutdown.sh"

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with shutdown on 2.1.x See: [Joe Taras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377807/orientdb-fails-to-shut-down/39179439#comment63666268_34377807) comment. You should update to the latest 2.2.x version.

Comment: it is possible to shutdown the server using the built in sh files in the bin directory "orientdb.sh stop" command or the "shutdown.sh" commands. I feel it is not that issue.